# Does a software gets installed every time I run its binary file?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center, tar, binary

So my doubt might sound funny but I am kind of new to ubuntu and want to get a clarity of different ways of installing software like .deb, .rpm, tarball. So considering the case of tarball. In some cases when i download a tarball and extract it i couldn't find the ./configure file, then with a little googling i understood that we need to run binary inside bin file since that extracted folder has binaries. So my question is will the software gets installed every time I run the binary file? Could anyone also explain how this works?

Comment: Tar files are always "as is" so do not require installation. Maybe setting up but that is it. Tar also has permission already set for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you install a .deb or .rpm file, it gets installed to the system. It is recognized as a software (which uses different SDKs). But the binary files are independently run, which don't need system integration and recognition. Installing .deb, .rpm files are analogous to running setups (on Windows), and bin files are like executing a script(.exe on Windows).

Generally big softwares like vscode, text editor, etc are .deb, .rpm packages.
Whereas small utilities like the ones show system information, etc are binary files.

Note: this has covered the general case. Some big softwares are also supplied as binaries and some small software might be .rpm or .deb packages.